# How to correctly make a get request during onChange

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to make a get request 2 seconds after the key is pressed on onChange. I'm using useForm and I know it can be done via lodash.throttle but it's not necessary for me. Help me write a function please

**this is my get request**

> const response = await searchContractorsById(data.INN);

```
<Controller
                  name="inn"
                  control={control}
                  render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
                    <TextField
                      value={value}
                      onChange={onChange}
                      type="number"
                      fullWidth
                      size="small"
                      placeholder="Например, 6163152794"
                      error={!!errors?.inn}
                      helperText={errors?.inn && errors.inn?.message}
                    />
                  )}
                />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you wish to do this request at **every** onChange, you can do something like this:

```
const handleChange = (event, onChange) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          searchContractorsById(data.INN)
            .then(() => {...use results here})
            .catch(e => ...)
        }, 2000)
        onChange(event)
      }

<Controller
  name="inn"
  control={control}
  render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
    <TextField
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, onChange)}
      type="number"
      fullWidth
      size="small"
      placeholder="Например, 6163152794"
      error={!!errors?.inn}
      helperText={errors?.inn && errors.inn?.message}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: but i want when you press the key after 2 seconds call api . There's more to be added setTimeout ?

Comment: Yes sorry i forgot to add it, now i edited the answer

Comment: I'm sorry, can you tell me how to wrap it in a separate function, write it before return jsx

Comment: Im sorry. Well, I want to stop the timeout when I press the button, if I haven’t pressed it for 2 seconds, then the call request

Comment: You need the [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout) function, save the timeout id (like so: const timeoutId = setTimeout(...), you can use useState or useRef to do this. Then when you want to cancel it use clearTimeout(timeoutId)

Comment: can you tell me where it is create lodash debounce